# How to use same file name with dynamic import() in webpack?

Tags: webpack

Assuming I have the following files:

- ./a.js
- ./b.js
- ./c.js

The following webpack config:

```
{
    ...
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].[hash:5].js',
        chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash:5].js',
    }
    ...
}
```

And I have an import as follows:

``` import(/* webpackChunkName: "path/to/[request]" */ ``./${name}.js``); ```

Webpack will generate chunks with the following names:

- path/to/a-js.js
- path/to/b-js.js
- path/to/c-js.js

Is there any way to remove `-js` from the chunk names so that they are the same as the original?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you didn't set your webpack config file properly like ["output.chunkfilename"](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-chunkfilename)

Can you show your webpack config?

Comment: I added the `output` part of my webpack config as you requested.